# Assigning a value to an object in Java

Tags: java, object, abstract-class

I have 3 classes (abstract) `Number`, `One` (extends `Number`), `Next` (extends `Number`).
I want to assign value 1 to object of type One so that calling:

```
Number one = new One();
Number four = new Next(new Next(new Next(one)));
System.out.println(one.toString());
System.out.println(four.toString()):`
```

prints:

```
1
n(n(n(1)))
```

Comment: Cool. What prevents you from doing so? (You may want to read [ask].)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you're asking, override the `Object.toString` method.

In `One`:

```
 @Override public String toString() {
     return "1";
 }
```

In `Next`:

```
 @Override public String toString() {
     return "n("+next+")";
 }
```

Assuming you `Next` field for the next node is called `next`.

You may also wish to make `toString` abstract in `Number`:

```
 @Override public abstract String toString();
```